# Alternating Divergent Sequences

Tags: real-analysis

If I have a sequence $ a_n $ that is divergent, then is it true that $ b_n =(-1)^na_n $ is also divergent?

This comes into play when I am trying to show that $\{ c_n=(-1)^nsin(n)\}$ is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $a_n = (-1)^n$, then $b_n = 1$.

If a subsequence of a sequence is divergent, then the sequence itself is divergent. What can you say about convergence of $\{c_{2n}\}$?

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n$ is divergent, we do not say anything about $b_n=(-1)^na_n$.

- If $a_n=(-1)^n$, then $b_n=1$ for all $n$ and hence $b_n$ is convergent.
- If $a_n=n$, then $b_n=(-1)^nn$ is divergent.

For your sequense, $c_n=(-1)^n\sin n$ is divergent.